# Test of proportions - proportion with CI versus given value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, survival, proportion

I am working on one clinical trial, where the primary goal is to compare proportion of overall survival (OS prop) after 12 months between our study and other registration study. I computed the OS prop in our sample (also with CI) and I would like to compare it to the OS prop from registration study and I would like to also somehow use the information from CI.

Also our sample is quite small (10 patients with 3 events after 12 months).

Could you help me find some appropriate test or could you point me in right direction?

thank you for any advice,
Matyas

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question. If it does, please click on the check mark on the left margin below to "accept" it.

Comment: Thank you, but how to take into account censored patients? Let say that out of this 10 patients 4 are censored without event. So I have 3 patients with event and 3 without event. So I should do Fisher exact test with those frequencies and let the censored out?

Comment: I came across this solution in PASS software manual <http://www.ncss.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Logrank_Tests.pdf> for Proportion Surviving Parameterization but I wished I found something for R, SPSS or SAS ... I couldnt find much more about it on web ....

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two proportions with the expected cell counts possibly below $5$, so you may want to opt for a Fisher exact test.

Let me simulate the data starting off with the points you provide, and pretend that the other institution ("Theirs") saw $2$ survivors out of $18$ patients, as opposed to your ("Our") $3$ of of $10$.

The data would tabulate as:

```
           Site
Survival    Our Theirs Sum
  Survivors   3      2   5
  Deceased    3     16  19
  Sum         6     18  24
```

And the Fisher test would be:

```
Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  OS
p-value = 0.07849
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
   0.5676368 122.6296405
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  7.102497
```

The expected counts would indeed be below $5$ in some cells:

```
Survival    Our Theirs Sum
Survivors   3      2   5
Deceased    3     16  19
Sum         6     18  24
```